# Powershell script that imports a CSV, compares the info to Active Directory, sorts it by OU, then exports the Info to csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to make a script that imports a csv with a single column, and searches active directory for the items in the csv (usernames), then records the OUs that those usernames are in and exports the results to a new csv.

What I've created so far I believe there is a syntax issue because when the new csv is made, it has pretty much every OU that exists on the domain. Not just the OU's that the usernames are in.

```
import-csv "C:\import.csv" | ForEach {get-aduser -Filter *} 
           | Select-object "OU" | export-csv -Path C:\export1.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will give you what you are trying to get. It will import your current CSV, loop through the users to get the OU and then export it.

```
$Data = import-csv "C:\import.csv"

$OutData = ForEach {$Line in $Data) {
    Get-ADUser $Line | Select-object Name, CanonicalName
}

$OutData | Export-Csv -Path C:\export1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The Identity property on the argument is null or empty.
At line:4 char:16
+     Get-ADUser $Line | Select-object Name, CanonicalName
+                ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: The import.csv has no header. Just one coulumn of usernames, if this matters.

Comment: Use `Get-Content` instead of `Import-Csv` in that case, then.

Comment: If you type `Get-ADuser` in PS with a specific user, does it give a result?

Comment: cmdlet Get-ADUser at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Filter: